# Beautiful soup how to remove links *and* the link text from soup

Tags: beautifulsoup, href

I'm using beautiful soup to get some cleaned up text from a webpage - no html, just the text that's shown to the user. However I don't really want the code to see text that has a link attached as visible text. To make clear what I mean here:

[This text is the problem](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

The above text links to the Beautiful soup documentation. At present I cut out the actually link, but the text 'This text is the problem' remains. Ideally I would like to remove that text also.

Comment: So you want to exclude all `<a>` tags from your soup?

Comment: Yes! Is there an inbuilt method for this?

Comment: yup. Find all `<a>` tags with `href=True`, and remove those. See solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the `<a>` tags with `href`. Either do `.extract()` or `.decompose()`:

Here it is in full:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
<p>I'm using beautiful soup to get some cleaned up text from a webpage - no html, just the text that's shown to the user. However I don't really want the code to see text that has a link attached as visible text. To make clear what I mean here: </p>
<p><a href="https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">This text is the problem</a></p>
<p>The above text links to the Beautiful soup documentation. At present I cut out the actually link, but the text 'This text is the problem' remains. Ideally I would like to remove that text also.</p>
    </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

p_tags = soup.find_all('p')

for each in p_tags:
    print (each.text)
```

**Output:**

```
I'm using beautiful soup to get some cleaned up text from a webpage - no html, just the text that's shown to the user. However I don't really want the code to see text that has a link attached as visible text. To make clear what I mean here: 
This text is the problem
The above text links to the Beautiful soup documentation. At present I cut out the actually link, but the text 'This text is the problem' remains. Ideally I would like to remove that text also.
```

And then by removing it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
<p>I'm using beautiful soup to get some cleaned up text from a webpage - no html, just the text that's shown to the user. However I don't really want the code to see text that has a link attached as visible text. To make clear what I mean here: </p>
<p><a href="https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">This text is the problem</a></p>
<p>The above text links to the Beautiful soup documentation. At present I cut out the actually link, but the text 'This text is the problem' remains. Ideally I would like to remove that text also.</p>
    </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    a.extract()

p_tags = soup.find_all('p')

for each in p_tags:
    print (each.text)
```

**Output:**

```
I'm using beautiful soup to get some cleaned up text from a webpage - no html, just the text that's shown to the user. However I don't really want the code to see text that has a link attached as visible text. To make clear what I mean here: 

The above text links to the Beautiful soup documentation. At present I cut out the actually link, but the text 'This text is the problem' remains. Ideally I would like to remove that text also.
```

You could also use `.decompose()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
<p>I'm using beautiful soup to get some cleaned up text from a webpage - no html, just the text that's shown to the user. However I don't really want the code to see text that has a link attached as visible text. To make clear what I mean here: </p>
<p><a href="https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">This text is the problem</a></p>
<p>The above text links to the Beautiful soup documentation. At present I cut out the actually link, but the text 'This text is the problem' remains. Ideally I would like to remove that text also.</p>
    </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.a.decompose()

p_tags = soup.find_all('p')

for each in p_tags:
    print (each.text)
```